# Twitter API: "TwitterError: The text of your tweet is too long."

Tags: twitter

I'm using Twitter's python API to broadcast tweets. Sometimes it works fine. Sometimes it gives me the error "The text of your tweet is too long" for tweets that I believe should be completely legal.

This website explains that all links within a tweet should basically be counted as 20 characters: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tco-link-wrapper/faq#How_do_I_calculate_if_a_Tweet_with_a_link_is_going_to_be_over_140_characters_or_not

But still it doesn't work for me. I have a tweet that is 132 characters. It includes the link bit.ly/YmoXqw. (That is a made-up link. But the size and form of the link is the same). And it gives me the error above. By my calculations, even if I count this link as 20 characters, it would still come out to 139 characters which is less than 140. So what's the solution here?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than hard-coding the number, you can query [help/configuration](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/help/configuration) and use *short_url_length_https* and *short_url_length*. Twitter's [Working with t.co Best Practices](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tco-url-wrapper/best-practices) guidance recommends caching these values up to 24-hours. Twitter recently announced [Upcoming t.co changes](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/upcoming-tco-changes) where the lengths were increasing. You might be seeing that and potentially running into miscalculations on power tweets due to differences in http and https lengths.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. How can I use the Python-Twitter API to query help/configuration?

when I looked at the function names made available by the API, none seemed like they would do this:

>>> dir(api)
['ClearCredentials', 'CreateFavorite', 'CreateFriendship', 'CreateList', 'CreateSubscription', 'DEFAULT_CACHE_TIMEOUT', 'DestroyDirectMessage', 'DestroyFavorite', 'DestroyFriendship', 'DestroyList', 'DestroyStatus', 'DestroySubscription', 'GetDirectMessages', 'GetFavorites', 'GetFeatured', 'GetFollowerIDs', 'GetFollowers', 'GetFriendIDs', 'GetFriends', 'GetFriendsTimeline', 'GetLists',

Comment: The Python Twitter API does have a member _shortlink_size. I thought that's the one I need. But this value comes out to be 19. Whereas clearly https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/help/configuration shows it to be 22. So what gives?